# Measure execution time java

Tags: jfr, async-profiler

I need to measure how many seconds takes to execute a particular method via JFR. It is possible to do that? I tried async-profiler but I don't this feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the source code, you can create an event:

```
@StackTrace(false)
@Name("MethodExecution")
@Label("Method Execution")
static class MethodExecution extends jdk.jfr.Event {
}

public void foo() {
   MethodExecution event = new MethodExecution();
   event.begin();
   bar();
   event.commit();
}
```

Then start JFR:

```
$ java -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=measurement.jfr ...
```

Open the file in [JDK Mission Control](https://jdk.java.net/jmc/8/), or use the 'jfr' utility to print the results:

```
$ jfr print --events MethodExecution measurement.jfr
```

If you don't have access to the source, you may want to look into the JMC Agent that can add similar code like above using bytecode instrumentation.